# I Need a fast way to loop through pixels of an Image/Stack in Python

Tags: python, image, loops, numpy, pixel

I have created a 3D median filter which does work and is the following:

```
def Median_Filter_3D(image,kernel):

window = np.zeros(shape=(kernel,kernel,kernel), dtype = np.uint8)
n = (kernel-1)/2    #Deals with Image border
imgout = np.empty_like(image)
w,h,l = image.shape()
```

%%Start Loop over each pixel

```
for y in np.arange(0,(w-n*2),1):
    for x in np.arange(0,(h-n*2),1):
        for z in np.arange(0,(l-n*2),1):
            window[:,:,:] = image[x:x+kernel,y:y+kernel,z:z+kernel]
            med = np.median(window)
            imgout[x+n,y+n,z+n] = med 
return(imgout)
```

So at every pixel, It creates a window of size kernelxkernelxkernel, finds the median value of the pixels in the window, and replaces the value of that pixel with the new medium value.

My problem is, its very slow, I have thousands of big images to process. There must be a faster way to iterate through all these pixels and still be able to get the same result.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, looping a 3D matrix in python is a very very very bad idea. In order to loop a large 3D matrix you are better of going down to [Cython](http://cython.org/) or C/C++/Fortran and creating a python extension. However, for this particular case, scipy already contains an implementation of the [median filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter.html#scipy-ndimage-filters-median-filter) for n-dimensional arrays:

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage import median_filter
>>> median_filter(my_large_3d_array, radious)
```

In short, there is no a *faster* way of iterating through voxels in python (maybe [numpy iterators](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html) would help a bit, but won't increase the performance considerably). If you need to perform more complicated 3D stuff in python, you should consider programming in Cython the *loopy* interface or, alternatively, using a chunking library such as [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/ghost.html#overlapping-blocks-with-ghost-cells), which implements *parallel* operations for chunks of arrays.

---

The problem with Python if that `for` loops are extremely slow, specially if they are nested and with large arrays. Thus, there is no a *standard pythonic* method for obtaining efficient iterations over arrays. Usually, the way of getting speed-ups is through vectorized operations and numpy-ticks, but those are very problem-specific and there is no generic *trick*, you will learn a lot of numpy tricks here in SO.

As a generic approach, if you really need to iterate over arrays, you can write your code in [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#primes). Cython is a C-like extension for Python. You write code in Python syntax, but specifying variable types (like in C, with `int` or `float`. That code is then compiled automatically to C and can be called from python. A quick example:

### Example Python loopy function:

```
import numpy as np

def iter_A(A):
    B = np.empty(A.shape, dtype=np.float64)

    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            B[i, j] = A[i, j] * 2
    return B
```

I know that the above code is kinda redundant and could be written as `B = A * 2`, but its purpose is just to illustrate that python loops are extremely slow.

### Cython version of the function:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def iter_A_cy(double[:, ::1] A):
    cdef Py_ssize_t H = A.shape[0], W = A.shape[1]
    cdef double[:, ::1] B = np.empty((H, W), dtype=np.float64)
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j

    for i in range(H):
        for j in range(W):
            B[i, j] = A[i, j] * 2

    return np.asarray(B)
```

### Test speeds of both implementations:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
>>> %timeit iter_A(A)
1 loop, best of 3: 399 ms per loop
>>> %timeit iter_A_cy(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.11 ms per loop
```

NOTE: you cannot run the Cython function as it is. You need to put it in a separate file and compile it first (or use `%%cython` magic in IPython Notebook).

It shows that the raw python version took `400ms` to iterate the whole array, while it was **only** `2ms` for the Cython version (`x200` speedup).

Comment: OK, thank you. I am a bit new to Python so don't know what Cython or Dask is yet but I will look into it (Y). I know scipy already has the filter but this is just a practice function that will lead to more complex ones later.

Comment: @ScottAlistair I've just edited the answer to give more information about Cython and why iterating large arrays in python is a bad idea. I know it is a lot to digest specially if you are new to python, but was just trying to point in the good direction.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful!

Comment: @ScottAlistair glad it helps! Note: `Py_ssize_t` is the equivalent (similar) to `size_t` in C if you are familiar with it (a large integer if not :P). To be able to use cython code you need to [compile](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html) it. And cython code is usually stored in `.pyx` files.